# How to manually destruct wrapped C++ class in Lua

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I would like to know if it's possible to manually destruct a C++ class in Lua.

I tried assigning `nil` to a class but it doesn't seem to work.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C" int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "local class = my.Class()\n"
                     "class = nil\n");
//    lua_close(L);
}
```

**MyBindings.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Class Constructed" << std::endl;
    };
    ~Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Class Destructed" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

**MyBindings.i**

```
%module my
%{
#include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**The Result I get:**

```
Class Constructed
```

**The Result I expect:**

```
Class Constructed
Class Destructed
```

It works if I call `lua_close(L);` or manually call a garbage callector `lua_gc(L, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);`

But I would like to learn if there's any other solution to manually destruct a C++ class in Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `Class` is wrapping some sort of resource in your program and you want to reclaim the memory.  To this end you could mimic the behaviour of `std::fstream`.  You can reclaim the resource at any point by calling the `close()` method.  If you do not explicitly call `close()`, the destructor will call it for you.  However, this entails that you are required to encode the valid state in your object.  I do this using a boolean which has to be checked before any access.

I assume it was only for the sake of demonstration that you omitted `lua_close(L)`, but you should never exit the program without closing the Lua state.  Otherwise finalizers might not be called.  For example buffered contents might not be written to file when abruptly quitting without calling `lua_close(L)`.

**`MyBindings.i`**

```
%module my
%{
#include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**`MyBindings.h`**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Class {
    bool m_valid{true};

public:
    Class() { std::cout << "Class Constructed" << std::endl; }

    void action() {
        if (!m_valid) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Use after free");
        }
        // do something
    }

    void close() {
        std::cout << "Class Destructed" << std::endl;
        m_valid = false;
    }

    ~Class() {
        if (m_valid) {
            close();
        }
    }
};
```

**`Main.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C" int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    if (luaL_dostring(L, "local class = my.Class()\n"
                         "class:close()\n") != 0) {
        std::cerr << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    std::cout << "Closing...\n";
    lua_close(L);
}
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -c++ -lua MyBindings.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/lua5.2/ Main.cpp MyBindings_wrap.cxx -llua5.2
$ ./a.out 
Class Constructed
Class Destructed
Closing...
```